# Access android "Application" Object from inside custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view that extends "Relative Layout" (actually is a custom listview item). 
I have no way to pass the application object to this view. Then how could I access the application object from inside this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getContext().getApplicationContext()`.